# python pandas , create a new column from an existing column , take the x n umber of characters from a string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a dataframe:

Project

---

The Bike Shop - London

Car Dealer - New York

Airport - Berlin

I want to add 2 new columns to the dataframe : business & location.

i can find where the  "-" is in the string by using:
df['separator'] = df['Project'].str.find('-')

whats the best and cleanest way to get 2 new fields into the dataframe?
ie, ProjectType & Location

Project                  ProjectType    Location

---

The Bike Shop - London   the Bike Shop  London

Car Dealer - New York    Car Dealer     New York

Airport - Berlin         Airport        Berlin

thanks in advance :)

Comment: you might want to format your question a little. Are you asking to split a column into two?

Comment: I think it would help to see some existing code and maybe a screenshot of your dataframe as it is right now. `.split(' - ')` might be better to use than `str.find()` from what I'm understanding so far.

Comment: code:
df['Pos'] = df['Project'].str.find('-')
df['ProjectType'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Project'][0:x['Pos']],axis=1).str.strip()
df['Location'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Project'][x['Pos']:],axis=1).str.strip()

Comment: sorry for crap format, i tried to make it cleaner, was not able to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, your current dataframe looks something like this:

[image]

and you want it to look like this:

[image]

If that's what you're looking for, you can use a list comprehension:

```py
df['ProjectType'] = [project.split(' - ')[0] for project in df['Project']]
df['Location'] = [project.split(' - ')[1] for project in df['Project']]
del df['Project'] # If you want to remove the original column
```

Comment: awesome ! :) very helpful

Comment: @MrPaul no problem. `.split()` is probably the piece you were missing. It simply returns a list of strings that were separated by the characters you specify as input. Then you can index into that list to choose the first, second, etc item.

Answer (score 1):

if your data is separated by '-', you can split it into several columns at once

```
new_df = df['new_values'].str.split('\n',expand=True)
```

here it is well described how to divide the column into others
http://datalytics.ru/all/kak-v-pandas-razbit-kolonku-na-neskolko-kolonok/

Comment: cheers, very useful indeed :)